# Python help random shuffler

Tags: python-3.x

So, I started learning Python at codecademy and I'm trying to create a program where you input a word and it scrambles it for you. However, I'm having trouble finding out how to go about it. This is what I have so far.

```
#Scrambler is a game that will take a given word and scramble it
print ("Welcome to Scrambler!")

word = input("Enter a word:") 

if len(word) > 0 and word.isalpha():
print (random.shuffle (word))
elif word.isalpha == False:
print ("Sorry, please try again") 
else: 
print ("Sorry, please try again")
```

*it says that 'random' is not defined, but I looked up the commands in Python and it says that random.shuffle() is a built in function.

Comment: `random.shuffle()` is not built-in; you need to `import random` first.

Answer (score 1):

random is a module that is included in the Python Standard Library, but you still need the 'import' statement to access it's functions.

additionally random.shuffle() only works with iterables and wont work with strings. you could however split the word into a list, shuffle it, then join it back together.

```
import random

print ("Welcome to Scrambler!")

word = input("Enter a word:") 

if len(word) > 0 and word.isalpha():
    letters = [i for i in word]
    random.shuffle(letters)
    print (''.join(letters))
elif word.isalpha == False:
    print ("Sorry, please try again") 
else: 
    print ("Sorry, please try again")
```

Comment: Pretty good, you forget to add the parenthesis on the second isalpha :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need:

1. import random as others said
2. use a list for random.shuffle
3. shuffle modify the list in place so split in two lines, shuffle then print
4. parenthesis are missing on you second call to isalpha
5. your indentation was broken

So the result will be:

```
import random
#Scrambler is a game that will take a given word and scramble it
print ("Welcome to Scrambler!")

word = input("Enter a word:") 

if len(word) > 0 and word.isalpha():
    wordaslist = list(word)
    random.shuffle(wordaslist)
    print (''.join(wordaslist))
elif word.isalpha() == False:
    print ("Sorry, please try again") 
else: 
    print ("Sorry, please try again")
```

Comment: Found why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item